# constructing tuple of classes type from template argument types

Tags: c++, tuples, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I would like to construct a type which is a tuple of same class with different template argument types. I mean:

Imagine we have a class

```
template<class Arg>
class A
{
    //.... details
}
```

I want to define something like:

```
template<class... Args>
struct construct_tuple 
{
    //assume I can access Args[...]
    using type = std::tuple<A<Args[0]>, A<Args[1]>, ..., A<Args[n]>>;
}
```

Could you please help?

I believe there might be a solution by iterating over the variadic arguments and using conctenation between tuple types or maybe using some other TMP e.g. `std::enable_if` or `std::conditional_t`.

Comment: `using type = std::tuple<A<Args>...>;` I'm sure there's a duplicate for this somewhere but don't have time to check right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your code doesn't try to **construct** anything, this will compile and provide what you want.

```
template<class... Args>
struct construct_tuple 
{
    //assume I can access Args[...]
    using type = std::tuple<A<Args>...>;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use the pack expansion,  Using:

```
using type = std::tuple<A<Args>...>;
```

Will expand to:

```
using type = std::tuple<A<Args1>, A<Args2>, ..., A<ArgsN>>;
```